How can I make an update route with express and sequelize?
I am trying to make an update route using NODE (Express and Sequelize).
I'm having trouble trying to make the update item for my database.
Here is how I'm trying to do it:
    app.put('/updateitem/:id', async(req, res)=>{
        const itemId = req.params.id;
        const resultado = await item.replaceOne({_id: itemId}, req.body)
        console.log(resultado)
        Item.update({
            Codigo: req.body.Codigo,
            Descricao: req.body.Descricao,
            Quantidade: req.body.Quantidade,
            Preco: req.body.Preco,
            Pcompra: req.body.Pcompra,
            Lucroliq: req.body.Preco - req.body.Pcompra,
            Lucro: (((req.body.Preco - req.body.Pcompra) / req.body.Pcompra) * 100).toFixed(2),},
            {where: {'id': req.params.id}})})


I'm also using Handlebars which I don't think is handling the item id in the url in the correct way.
<form action="/updateitem:id" method="PUT">
    <p>Código</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{item.Codigo}}" name="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo  do Produto"> <br><br><br>
    <p>Descrição</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{item.Descricao}}" name="Descricao" placeholder="Descricao do Produto"> <br><br><br>
    <p>Quantidade</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{item.Quantidade}}" name="Quantidade" placeholder="Quantidade de itens"> <br><br><br>
    <p>Preço</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{item.Preco}}" name="Preco" placeholder="Preço do Produto"><br><br><br>
    <p>Preço de Compra</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{item.Pcompra}}" name="Pcompra" placeholder="Preço de Compra"> <br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

I also tried using <form action="/updateitem:{{id}}" method="PUT"> and <form action="/updateitem:{{item.id}}" method="PUT"> and they both didn't work (maybe because of the put route).

It looks like your action would need to be /updateitem/{{item.id}}.

<form action="/updateitem/{{item.id}}" method="PUT">


i tried like that and still, nothing my routes are like this
`app.put('/updateitem/:id', async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        const itemId = req.params.id;
    console.log(itemId)
    const resultado = await Item.update({_id: itemId}, req.body)
    console.log(resultado)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }`

 app.get('/edititem/:id', function(req, res){         Item.findOne({where: {'id': req.params.id}}).then(function(item){             res.render('editItem.handlebars', {item: item})         })     })

You are not giving the community enough information to help you. We don't know if the route is incorrect or there is an error in your route handler. Are you seeing anything logged on the server-side when you submit your form? What errors are you getting? And where?
